# Change of integration and differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

Consider $\beta>0$, $i$ the imaginary number and $t$ a variable. Is it possible to change differentiation and integration like in the following?

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^\infty e^{-(\beta-it) x}\frac{1}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dt} e^{-(\beta-it) x}\frac{1}{x}dx$$

such that we get

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^\infty e^{-(\beta-it) x}\frac{1}{x}dx= i \int_0^\infty e^{-(\beta-it) x}dx$$

?

Comment: Yes, because stuff converges quickly enough

Comment: But what would happen when $x\to 0^+$? Does the integral converge?

Comment: The integral fails to exist due to the $\frac1x$ singularity at $x=0$.  So, differentiating a divergent object is nonsensical.